# Linking metis to wrapped C++ module using Cython

Tags: c++, linker, cython, metis

I am trying to link the metis library during the compiling of the Cython source file but I am having difficulties as I am getting undefined symbols in the compiled shared object file.

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with linking external libraries such as metis using distutils? Would a better option be using makefile?

What I have done:

Adding the directory to libmetis.a in extra_link_args

Comment: If you put your setup.py file in your post it might help to answer. Plus a little sketch of the (cython) code you are compiling.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this issue which is instead of using distutils, I used makefile to compile which makes the linking much easier.

Comment: So the original OP saying he's solved his problem is not an answer to the question? How do you reckon that?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need

```
python setup.py build_clib
```

before

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

If this doesn't help, is the undefined symbol `_Py_ZeroStruct` ? That would be because you did `python setup.py build_ext` and used from python 3. For that, you'll need `python3` command.

Hope this helps.